# How to set color range in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colors

Looking for some help on properly coding the color range, and how to set the colors.  Currently I am getting the default color range and I am unsure how to change the range and also the colors selected.  I assume the code should be either in the plot method or near it.  Looking to change the default purple to yellow to a custom set, while also manually setting the ranges.

Sales range from 0-15

Code:

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,12))
ax = AZ3.plot(column='Sales',ax=ax,edgecolor='black')
f.suptitle('AZ')
lims = plt.axis('equal')

patchList = []

for key in legend_dict:
        data_key = mpatches.Patch(color=legend_dict[key], label=key)
        patchList.append(data_key)

plt.legend(handles=patchList, loc=3)
plt.savefig('legend.png', bbox_inches='tight')

for idx, row in AZ3.iterrows():
    plt.annotate(s=row['Name'], xy=row['coords'],
                horizontalalignment='center', color='white', size=(12))
```

Map:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0tMU.jpg)

Sample Data:

```
FIPS    Name    State   Sales
04007   Gila     AZ       1
04027   Yuma     AZ       10
04012   La Paz   AZ       6
04019   Pima     AZ       5
04009   Graham   AZ       2
04021   Pinal    AZ       7
04025   Yavapai  AZ       3
04001   Apache   AZ       8
04023   Santa    AZ       9
04005   Coco     AZ       0
04003   Cochise  AZ       0
04011   Green    AZ       0
04013   Maricopa AZ       15
04015   Mohave   AZ       1
04017   Navajo   AZ       4
```

Thanks,

Justin

Comment: Can you please include a small sample of data that you're trying to plot?

Comment: Data added in, FIPS, County name, State, Sales (ranging 0-15) thanks.  It is really setting up specific bins that I am looking for help with.  Such as 0 is one color, 1-3 is another color, 4-6 is another, and so forth.  I have a colormap, so I just need help with manual bins.